# How can I increase the distance of a photodiode

Tags: photodiode, detection

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWDcG9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I wanted to make a fire detection system using a photodiode, comparator with potentiometer to adjust sensitivity, and an alarm circuit after that. My question is, how can I increase the range of a photodiode so that I can detect a fire about 20 feets away or more? Is this possible? Thank you.

Comment: We can't suggest modifications to your circuit if you don't show it to us. You can a schematic using the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar. Double-click a component to edit its properties. 'R' = rotate, 'H' = horizontal flip. 'V' = vertical flip. 

Note that when you use the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar and "Save and Insert" on the editor an editable schematic is saved in your post. That makes it easy for us to copy and edit in our answers. You don't need a CircuitLab account, no screengrabs, no image uploads, no background grid.

Comment: try using a lens

Comment: @vicatcu, if I understand correctly,  the source is the flame being detected. Replacing it with a laser would defeat the purpose.

Comment: We will need a full discussion from you about the circumstances. Almost certainly, most of a good answer will not be about electronics but instead about the type of detector you should select and perhaps optical considerations. Also, you should search around to see if there is a product that already achieves your goals and let us know about those, too (and add a note about why you don't want to just "buy one.")

Comment: It is critical to select a good photodiode or phototransistor with the correct IR range included and visible light filtered out, e.g. https://www.sunrom.com/p/flame-sensor-5mm-ir-diode-yg1006

Comment: pjc50 I looked at that but it seems to work at a distance of about 1 feet

Comment: The yg1006 has good daylight blocking and voltage gain can be increased with load R to 1M but at 20' or 6m with a 120 deg viewing angle any other source of light must be blocked such as artificial and sunlight.That makes your idea perhaps unusable. Try again.

Comment: It's going to depend critically on your sensing environment. In a pitch black room, a simple lens, filter and photodiode will work. Add in any sources of NIR light (incandescents, sunlight, etc) and this becomes much harder. Give us some more details.